# $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ then does the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to a} (f(x)- g(x))=0$?

Tags: limits, examples-counterexamples

Assuming $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ then I'm wonderin if the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to a} (f(x)- g(x))=0$, always?

---

You see, I was trying to see if the definitions for two asymptotic curves were equivalent. That is, the two definitions,

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} (f(x)- g(x))=0 \iff  \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ where $a \in [-\infty, \infty]$

After battling with this for the last half an hour, I have been able to produce a counterexample for $(\Rightarrow)$ which is pretty simple, take $f(x)=g(x)=0$. As for the $(\Leftarrow)$, I can also produce a counterexample for when $a ∈ \{±\infty\}$, take $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be polynomials of same degree like $f(x)=x^{99}, g(x)=x^{99}+7$, so the highest degree term dominates in the numerator and the denominator, hence limit of quotient is $1$ but difference is non-zero.

For the life of me, I can't come up with any pair of functions for the case $(\Leftarrow)$ when $a \in (-∞, ∞)$. I'm starting to believe it is actually true. Intuitively, it should be since it means near $a$, if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} ≈1$ then $f(x)≈ g(x)$ but my intuition has failed me enough times to know better than to rely on it. Any help?

---

Obviously, with this exercise, I have come to realize that the two definitions are not equivalent but I can't help but wonder why? Why are two definitions saying different things?

Comment: Hint. What happenes $\lim f(x)=\infty$?

Comment: If both $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exist (and are finite), the answer is yes.

Comment: @Nightflight I have already tried considering that case (in my rough work) but I haven't included it here because the question would become unnecessarily confusing and big. Every example, I could come up with, for infinite limits of f(x) and g(x), produced the limit of difference to be $0$. Like $f(x)= \sec x$ and $g(x)= \tan x$ at $x = π/2$. Quotient is $1$ but different also turns out to be $1$ :(

Comment: @PierreCarre Well I'm not taking that as a given. Because then, yes, you're correct. $\lim(f/g) = \lim f / \lim g = 1 \iff \lim f = \lim g \iff \lim f - \lim g = \lim (f-g) =0$ assuming $\lim g ≠0$.

Comment: Whoever found the duplicate, can you tell me how did you even find it that quickly? I tried looking up for about 10 mins before I finally gave in and asked the question.

Comment: @William:  Duplicate found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim%5Climits_%7Bx%20%5Cto%20a%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bf(x)%7D%7Bg(x)%7D%3D1%24%2C%20AND%20content%3A%24%5Clim%5Climits_%7Bx%20%5Cto%20a%7D%20(f(x)-%20g(x))%3D0%24)

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L_1 < \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)= L_2$, it is easy to show that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{L_1}{L_2}$. So, in this framework, if the limit of the quotient is 1, both limits are the same and the limit of the difference is zero.

Therefore, a counterexample must come from unbounded limits, as the ones proposed by @5xum.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand this. (See my reply to your comment). Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Could you perhaps explain to me why the two limits are saying different things?

Comment: The two limits are not saying different things, it's just that when the individual limits are unbounded it is not admissible to say that they are equal, even if the quotient tends to 1.